# How to plot same point with two distinct makers having different Markersize and colour in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to use two distinct markers of different colour and size in MATLAB plot on same point for illustration purpose.

```
plot(100,200,'b*');
plot(100,200,'go','MarkerSize',12);
```

Though above two statement works perfectly, but i want to use it on a large number of points. Can above these two statements be combined into a single plot?

Comment: [this](http://freesourcecode.net/matlabprojects/63787/custom-marker-plot-in-matlab#.WM-QZt8Sr0o) looks related

Comment: Try putting a `hold on' before your commands (or in between them). This ensures the plot generated by the second command is overlaid with the first, rather than replacing it.

Comment: @shamalaia: Is there any in-bulit method to acheive it?

Answer (score 2):

just write a simple function yourself:

```
function emphasizePoint(X,Y)
    hold on;
    plot(X,Y,'b*');
    plot(X,Y,'go','MarkerSize',12);
end
```

and use it like

```
X = rand(1,100);
Y = rand(1,100);
emphasizePoint(X,Y);
```

Comment: i have to loop this plot command for a vector, function will make it slower. I need to combine these two statements into one, if available in MATLAB.

Comment: 1. You can plot a vector at once. 2. You can use such function in a loop if needed, it won't be much slower than use one plot() statement in the loop.

Comment: It's a better practice to add a `hold off` at the end of your function, just in case...